# Officially listed way of getting a Steam market item's price

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

I want an officially supported way to get the price of an item on the Steam Marketplace.

I tried the `https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamEconomy/GetAssetPrices/v0001/` endpoint too but it seems to price keys at 3.39$ CAD which is wrong because keys are around 2$. Which means that this are the official Steam prices which aren't marketplace prices.

I've found a way to obtain the prices of an item on the Steam Marketplace using [this post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29902280/get-price-of-item-in-steam-community-market-with-json). And after making a request to `https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=440&market_hash_name=Mann%20Co.%20Supply%20Crate%20Key` I get this, working, response.

```json
{"success":true,"lowest_price":"$2.22","volume":"21,426","median_price":"$2.21"}
```

Of course this is nice and all for what I'm writing but I'm unaware if this is something that I can reliably use without worry of a ratelimit/ban because I've read the [TF2 API docs](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/WebAPI) and have not found this endpoint. And the endpoint does not have "api" in it or requires a "&key=" argument which leads me to believe that this is a browser endpoint which is explicitly not allowed. Is this listed anywhere on the official Steam website with documentation? If not (which, as I understand, opens me to ratelimits/bans which I ***really*** want to avoid) are there any other free official or 3rd party endpoints (***with*** documentation) that I can use to get the market price of items (in USD & CAD)?